# Java Spring ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I don't have much experience with Java Spring and am currently trying to program a server. My WebSecurityConfig can be seen below. When I try to call /login I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I don't understand where exactly the redirection takes place. Can anyone explain to me?

I just want the login page to come up when you go to the login web address. It's currently running locally for me, so the web address is http://localhost:8080/login

EDIT: The status code of the response is 302. If I add a login.html file to the project, it works for /login.html, but if I try http://localhost:8080/api/v1/registration/ then, I am redirected to /login.html again. And if I remove the .formLogin(...) part, and try to call http://localhost:8080/api/v1/registration/, then it returns 403 Forbidden.

Thanks!

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                );

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

I tried reading the documentation but didn't help me much.

Comment: Please check your browser dev-tools network for HTTP messages between browser and server. Server is redirecting with 3xx response for /login to some other url in location header. Please trace the network call to identify the source of redirection in your server side code viz. any other security filter, url interceptor etc.

Comment: why not enable spring security trace logs and read them?

Comment: Because I didn't know that there is such a thing as trace logs. But I did it now and found the issue. My server was okey, the issue was in my requests. They need to have content-type : application/json and now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: It was also necessary to call .csrf().disable() by the way.